# Does Java's strictfp modifier apply through function calls?

Tags: java, floating-point, strictfp

More precisely, if there exists a function in the call stack with the strictfp modifier, will the function at the top of the call stack also adhere to the strictfp specifier?

```java
public class Main {

    // case 1: strictfp not present at top of call stack
    private static double bar1(double x) {
        return Math.sin(x);
    }

    strictfp private static double foo1(double x) {
        return bar1(x);
    }

    // case 2: strictfp present at top of call stack
    strictfp private static double bar2(double x) {
        return Math.sin(x);
    }

    strictfp private static double foo2(double x) {
        return bar2(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = 10.0;
        System.out.println(foo1(x)); // -0.5440211108893698
        System.out.println(foo2(x)); // -0.5440211108893698
    }
}
```

In this example, `foo1` and `foo2` appear to return the same value. In other words, it doesn't look like it matters whether the function at the top of the call stack has the strictfp modifier when a function further down also has the modifier.

Does this always hold true? What if I choose differing values for `x`? What if I choose floating point operations other than sine?

Comment: I think `strictfp` does not apply to method calls.  I think it's a compile time flag to compile the code in your class and method differently, it does not affect code you call that was compiled separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JLS 15.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4):

> If an expression is not a constant expression, then consider all the class declarations, interface declarations, and method declarations that contain the expression. If any such declaration bears the `strictfp` modifier (§8.1.1.3, §8.4.3.5, §9.1.1.2), then the expression is *FP-strict*.
>
> [...]
>
> It follows that an expression is not *FP-strict* if and only if it is not a constant expression and it does not appear within any declaration that has the `strictfp` modifier.

Therefore, calls to external methods or other ways of obtaining a floating-point expression do not "inherit" the FP-strictness of something up the call stack.